# How to calculate spherical coordinate $(x,y,z)$ of a star from magnitude, declination and right ascension?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

If the magnitude, right ascension and declination are $6.7, 1.29125$ & $45.22916667$ respectively. Is it possible to find out the position in spherical coordinate and how?

Comment: The use of the word 'magnitude' here is a little confusing given the more common meaning of that word in astronomy. (Probably 'radial coordinate' would be more appropriate.)

Answer (score 1):

*Stellar* magnitude is not needed; it is a measure of a star's brightness (usually apparent, if not otherwise stated).  If by magnitude you mean distance, then if we have distance $r$, declination $\delta$, and right ascension $\alpha$, we can compute

$$
x = r \cos\delta \cos\alpha
$$

$$
y = r \cos\delta \sin\alpha
$$

$$
z = r \sin\delta
$$

This puts a star right at the First Point of Aries ($0$ right ascension, $0$ declination) on the $x$-axis.

---

Incidentally, right ascension is often given in hours, minutes, and seconds, rather than digital degrees (as you have apparently done).  If that's the case, then you convert $H, M, S$ into degrees as

$$
\delta = 15H + \frac{M}{4} + \frac{S}{240}
$$

Declination is often given in degrees, minutes, and seconds; if so, then you convert $d, m, s$ into degrees as

$$
\alpha = d + \frac{m}{60} + \frac{s}{3600}
$$

---

I found no star of the $12$th magnitude or brighter in the location you gave (RA $3^\text{h} 0^\text{m} 55.0^\text{s}$, Dec $1^\circ 17' 29''$).  Is this supposed to be a real star?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Brian Tung. It's helpful. For curiosity, what if right ascension: 1.29125 & declination: 45.22916667 ?

Comment: Where did you get these numbers, if you don't mind my asking?

Comment: I am trying to help on star tracking and pattern recognition of university satellite project. We have a bright star catalog. However I have a very limited knowledge... :)

Comment: @RezwanShubh: What does the catalog say for this star, exactly (as close to the format as you can get)?